# if $P_n$ is the midpoint of the line segment joining $P_{n−2}$ and $P_{n−3}$, then prove area converges to 0

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

Consider a sequence $P_1,P_2,…$ of points in the plane such that $P_1,P_2,P_3$ are non-collinear and for every n≥4,$P_n$ is the midpoint of the line segment joining $P_{n−2}$ and $P_{n−3}$.

Let L denote the line segment joining P1 and P5. Prove that the area of the triangle formed by the points $P_n,P_{n−1},P_{n−2}$ converges to zero as n goes to infinity.

I thought of proving the question using coordinate system taking an arbitrary triangle but after $P_4$ and $P_5$ calculating $P_6$ disrupts the symmetry. Please suggest a way to navigate the problem.

Comment: I understand your question, but why do you define the line segment $L$, which seems to play no role?

Comment: Let $P_1=(0,0), P_2=(a,0), P_3=(b,c), c\neq 0$. Now calculate coordinates of $P_4, P_5,\ldots$ and evaluate areas of $\Delta$s. They'll come out to be in a geometric progression with common ratio $\frac 12$, hence proved.

Comment: @WhatsUp That was for the second part of the question, which I didn't mention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $O$ be an arbitrary point of the plane. Consider vectors $v_n:=\overrightarrow{OP_n}$. Then, for all $n\ge 3$ we have
$$
v_{n}=\frac{1}{2}(v_{n-2}+v_{n-3})
$$
or
$$
v_{n}-v_{n-1}=-(v_{n-1}-v_{n-2})-\frac{1}{2}(v_{n-2}-v_{n-3}).
$$
The area of the triangle $P_{n-2}P_{n-1}P_{n}$ equals the half of length of the cross product of $v_{n}-v_{n-1}$ and $v_{n-1}-v_{n-2}$. Put $u_n=v_{n}-v_{n-1}$. Then, for all $n\ge 3$ we have
$$
u_{n}=-u_{n-1}-\frac{1}{2}u_{n-2}.
$$
Now it suffices to prove that $[u_{n-1},u_{n}]\to 0$ when $n\to\infty$.

Can you continue now?

Answer (score 0):

For $n = 4, 5, 6, \ldots$, since $P_n$ is the midpoint of the segment joining the points $P_{n-3}$ and $P_{n-2}$, we can conclude that
$$
\vec{OP_n} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \vec{OP_{n-3}} + \vec{OP_{n-2}} \right). \tag{1}
$$

So
\begin{align}
& \ \ \ \mbox{area } \triangle P_{n-2} P_{n-1} P_n \\ 
&= \frac{1}{2} \left\lvert \vec{ P_{n-2} P_n } \times \vec{ P_{n-2} P_{n-1} } \right\rvert \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left\lvert \left( \vec{OP_n} - \vec{OP_{n-2} } \right) \times \left( \vec{OP_{n-1}} - \vec{OP_{n-2} } \right)  \right\rvert \\ 
&= \frac{1}{2} \left\lvert \left[ \frac{1}{2} \left( \vec{OP_{n-3}} + \vec{OP_{n-2}} \right) - \vec{OP_{n-2} }  \right] \times \left( \vec{OP_{n-1}} - \vec{OP_{n-2} } \right)  \right\rvert \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left\lvert \frac{1}{2} \left( \vec{OP_{n-3}} - \vec{OP_{n-2}} \right) \times \left( \vec{OP_{n-1}} - \vec{OP_{n-2}} \right) \right\rvert \\ 
&= \frac{1}{4} \left\lvert \vec{ OP_{n-1} } \times \vec{OP_{n-2}} + \vec{ OP_{n-2} } \times \vec{OP_{n-3}}    + \vec{ OP_{n-3} } \times \vec{OP_{n-1}}  \right\rvert \\
& = \ldots \ldots
\end{align}

To be honest, I'm not sure how to proceed from here. The above calculation might show you some way.